# Permissions for webparts

Tags: web-part, sub-site

I have a sitecollection, with two subsites, site1 and site2. 
On site2, I want to use a .html-file that is stored on site1, in a webpart.
Is there any way to grant permission to the site (and all of its users) to do this, or do I have to copy the .html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in this case would be if you can create the same page or copy that html page in Site 2 and that would be easy to manage. However, if you want to use the Site 1 page in Site 2, you need to grant permissions on both sites to users who should view that page.

**OR**

You should grant only desired users permissions on that specific HTML page by breaking its inheritance (Stop Inheriting Permissions from Parent). This way the unauthorized users will see an Access Denied error while authenticated users will see that page.

**OR**

The other way which i believe is pretty complex way for this simple need is to create Audience Groups in User Profile Service Application based on any differential user property and then set permissions for that Audience Groups under that Web Part properties.

[See how to create Audience Groups in SharePoint 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262169(v=office.14).aspx).